# Returns 404 if =404 is in try_files

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, config

Webpage always returns `404` if the `=404` is in the `try_files`

Webserver is Nginx
I can access `www.mydomain.com/admin/` just fine (contains a index.php)
if I go to `www.mydomain.com/player/players/` it doesn't work (players is `players.php`) and there are no index files in player.

Removing `=404` from the first `try_files` makes everything work as if there isn't anything wrong but then etc `www.mydomain.com/filethatdoesentexist/` returns "no input file"

My code

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @rewrite =404;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }

  rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;

  location /admin/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @rewrite;
  }
```

Comment: You could either have `@location` or `=code` not both as a last argument of `try_files`.

Comment: Also, you are missing a `try_files $uri =404;` in your `location ~ \.php$` block. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) for details.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issues